# How to resolve git am's "patch does not apply" as a merge conflict?

Tags: git

I'm looking to move some commits from one repository to another, and I'd like to maintain the original commits, date and commit messages and all, rather than squashing the whole thing together. `git format-patch master` got me that, making one .patch file per commit, but I'm having some trouble applying them (I'm stuck on the first commit).

`git apply <patch file name>` applies the changes cleanly, with no conflicts or anything, but of course it doesn't create the commit I'd like.

`git am --committer-date-is-author-date -3 < <patch file name>`, on the other hand, fails with no clear way to resolve it:

```
Applying: <original commit message>
error: patch failed: war/WEB-INF/web.xml:162
error: war/WEB-INF/web.xml: patch does not apply
<more files listed, all of them ones that I've modified in the commit; newly created files are not listed>
error: Did you hand edit your patch?
It does not apply to blobs recorded in its index.
hint: Use 'git am --show-current-patch' to see the failed patch
Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
M       war/WEB-INF/web.xml
Patch failed at 0001 <commit message>
When you have resolved this problem, run "git am --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git am --skip" instead.
To restore the original branch and stop patching, run "git am --abort".
```

After running this, there are no changes in my working copy or staged. I'd have expected to get changed files with merge conflict style marks (`<<<<<<<<` and `>>>>>>>>`), since I used the `-3` flag, but I don't even have that.

Is there a way to run `git am` to get what I'm after, or should I use `git apply` and make new commits?

Comment: Try `--reject`. The conflicting hunks are kept in `.rej` files.

Comment: Thanks @ElpieKay! Conflict resolution was a bit different, but it got me what I was after - it let me keep the original commit messages, dates and contents. If you post it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try [--reject](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply#Documentation/git-apply.txt---reject). It applies the parts of the patch that are applicable, and leave the rejected hunks in corresponding *.rej files. It helps when `-3` doesn't work well.

UPDATE:

As you create patches from the commits by `git format-patch`, it means you have the Git metadata. It would be more friendly to use `git rebase` or `git cherry-pick`. These commands handle with conflicts in a better and smarter way than `git apply` or `git am`.

Before `git rebase` or `git cherry-pick`, you need to transfer the metadata from one repository to the other. Suppose the source repository and the target repository lie on the same machine.

```
# go to the target repository
cd /path/to/target

# fetch master from the source repository
git fetch /path/to/source master:source_master

# browse the log of source_master
git log source_master

# switch to the target branch
git switch target_branch

# apply the commits
git cherry-pick commit1 commit2 ...

# if any conflicts, resolve them
# edit the conflicted files which have conflict markers

# add edited files, and end the conflicts
git add conflicted_files
git cherry-pick --continue
```

In case the source repository and the target repository lie on different machines and there is no direct network between them, you can create a bundle from the source repository and copy the bundle to the target machine.

```
# go to the source repository
cd /path/to/source

# create a bundle master.bundle from master
git bundle create master.bundle master

# move master.bundle to the target machine and use it as a read-only repository
# go to the target repository
cd /path/to/target

# fetch master from master.bundle
git fetch /path/to/master.bundle master:source_master

# the rest are the same
```

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful but I really wish there was an option to just add the merge conflict markers instead of creating `.rej` files.

Comment: Convert `.rej` to merge conflict markers with `find . -iname '*.rej' -exec basename {} .rej ';' | xargs -I _ wiggle --replace _ _.rej`

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> Patch failed at 0001 <commit message>
> When you have resolved this problem, run "git am --continue".
> ```

`git am --help` says re `--continue`: "After a patch failure (e.g. attempting to apply conflicting patch), the user has applied it by hand and the index file stores the result of the application. Make a commit using the authorship and commit log extracted from the e-mail message and the current index file, and continue."

So, to resolve this problem manually, run in the clean working tree:

```
wiggle --merge --replace --patch .git/rebase-apply/0001   # the number from error message
git diff   # ensure that all changes are correctly applied
find . -not -path './.git/*' -type f -name '*.porig' -delete   # remove orig copies
git add -a
git am --continue
```